# Is the space of converging sequences in $\mathbb{N}$ with Euclidean metric $d_2$ countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

This was an exam problem today that I couldn't solve. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: No. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: perhaps you meant 1st diagonal proof, right? if so, all the sequences are not convergent! But every sequence in my space needs to be convergent!

Comment: Ah I did not see that the sequences need to be in $\mathbb{N}$. This changes things. It is just the countable union of countable sets in this case. So, yes, it is countable.

Comment: oh yes! I should have noticed it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

If $\langle x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a convergent sequence of integers, then there is some $k$ such that for all $n>k$, $x_n=x_k$. Show that given $n\in\Bbb N$ there can only be a countable collection of sequences converging to $n$, and conclude the wanted result.